# Method [create] is not supported by the gateway [paypal]

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-4, omnipay

I followed [this](http://solidmarkup.com/blog/using-omnipay-paypal-with-laravel)tutorial. I tried to integrate the paypal into my website. My purpose is to allow to user to send money to another user via a donation button using paypal.
my configuration :

```
      return array(

// The default gateway to use
'default' => 'paypal',

// Add in each gateway here
'gateways' => array(
    'paypal' => array(
        'driver' => 'PayPal_Express',
        'options' => array(
            'solutionType' => '',
            'landingPage' => '',
            'headerImageUrl' => ''
        )
    )
)
```

);

But when I call `$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');` I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException

Method [create] is not supported by the gateway [paypal].
```

How can I correct the problem here,is there any configuration I have to make before calling the create function?
Is there any way to integrate paypal payment in Laravel into my website?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I forget to call : `use Omnipay\Omnipay;` before getting into my controller class. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be $gateway = GatewayFactory::create('PayPal_Express');

Comment: Class 'GatewayFactory' not found